Ajax/Livewire not working in Laravel project hosted on XAMPP Apache but works with php artisan serve
I have a Laravel project that I previously developed using XAMPP Apache and MySQL, and everything worked perfectly. However, when I started implementing Ajax or Livewire components in my project, they don't seem to work when hosted on XAMPP Apache. Instead, they only work when I use 'php artisan serve' to serve the project.
When attempting to use Ajax, I encounter the following error in the browser console:
Not Found
The requested URL was not found on this server.
Apache/2.4.58 (Win64) OpenSSL/3.1.3 PHP/8.2.12 Server at localhost Port 80

img
I'm confident that it's a configuration issue or something similar. Can anyone shed light on why this might be happening and suggest how I can resolve it? Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

post your apache config

I found the solution
instead of giving the url this way in javascript ajax code:


    xhr.open("GET", "/get-article-codes?code=" + this.value, true);



You should give the full url including "http":


    xhr.open("GET", "http://localhost/MyApp/public/get-article-codes?code=" + this.value, true);



Make sure to change "MyApp" to your project folder name
